# How to sort an array by distance with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm still learning objective C and iOS and I'm running into a problem. I am creating an array from CoreData that contains latitudes and longitudes. I want to take this array and sort it by the closest location.

This is what I have so far:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *getProjects = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *projectsEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TimeProjects" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[getProjects setEntity:projectsEntity];
projectArray = [[context executeFetchRequest:getProjects error:&error] mutableCopy];

for (NSObject *project in projectArray) {
    // Get location of house
    NSNumber *lat = [project valueForKey:@"houseLat"];
    NSNumber *lng = [project valueForKey:@"HouseLng"];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[lat doubleValue];
    coord.longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[lng doubleValue];

    houseLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];
    //NSLog(@"House location: %@", houseLocation);

    CLLocationDistance meters = [houseLocation distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

}
```

I also have this sorting code but I'm not sure how to put the two together.

```
[projectArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id o1, id o2) {
    CLLocation *l1 = o1, *l2 = o2;

    CLLocationDistance d1 = [l1 distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
    CLLocationDistance d2 = [l2 distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
    return d1 < d2 ? NSOrderedAscending : d1 > d2 ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Can some one help me out with making these two things work together?

Comment: Did you put the `sortUsingComparator` section before your loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `sortUsingComparator` block expects `CLLocation` objects, not instances of your 
Core Data class. That would be easy to fix, but what I would recommend is:

- Add a *transient* property `currentDistance` to your entity. (Transient properties are not stored in the persistent store file.) The type should be "Double".
- After fetching the objects, compute the `currentDistance` for all objects in `projectArray`.
- Finally sort the `projectArray` array, using a sort descriptor on the `currentDistance` key.

The advantage is that the distance to the current location is calculated only once for each object, and not calculated repeatedly in the comparator method.

The code would look like this (not compiler checked!):

```
NSMutableArray *projectArray = ... // your mutable copy of the fetched objects
for (TimeProjects *project in projectArray) {
    CLLocationDegrees lat = [project.houseLat doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees lng = [project.houseLng doubleValue];
    CLLocation *houseLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lng];
    CLLocationDistance meters = [houseLocation distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
    project.currentDistance = @(meters);
}
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"currentDistance" ascending:YES]
[projectArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

Alternatively, you can make `currentDistance` a *persistent* property of the entity and calculate it when the object is created or modified. The advantage is that you could add
a sort descriptor based on `currentDistance` to the fetch request instead of fetching
first and sorting afterwards. The disadvantage is of course that you have to re-calculate
all values when the current location changes.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think your solution will work but I am running into a bug. When it runs, it crashes at project.currentDistance = @(meters); with the error: -[TimeProjects setCurrentDistance:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. I added @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *currentDistance; to my TimeProjects model header file.

Comment: @Keith: You cannot just add the property to the header file. You have to define currentDistance as a transient property in the Core Data model. Then you (re-)create the managed object subclass file.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I got it working. I've never used a transient property, I'll have to look into them more.